# Unique security scopes per list or library

Tags: document-library, permissions, limitations

I have a quick question about this limit [unique security scopes per list or library](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office365/servicedescriptions/sharepoint-online-service-description/sharepoint-online-limits#unique-security-scopes-per-list-or-library). Is in this number count 'children' files in folders? Let's say I have one document library with exactly 50k folders, without any child items. And I will be adding files in all these 50k folders that files will be always inherit permissions. It will be fine (beyond performance), or sub files or folders with inherit permissions also count towards this limit?